# retrieveduplicaterequest dynamic crm 2011 for a certain rule

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Is it possible to retrieve duplicate entities from a certain detect duplication rules using retrieveduplicaterequest?

For example, I have 2 duplicate detection rules for account:

Rule 1: Based on exact match for name
 Rule 2: Based on exact match for mobile phone

Can I query all the duplicates for account A **that is caused by Rule 1 only**? So in my results I can get all the other accounts with the exact same name, but none of the other accounts with the exact same mobile phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any method to achieve your goal, because the duplicate detection feature works slightly different.

The application does not evaluate the rules you define directly. The rules define which fields and which elements of them are used to create a sort of a hash. The duplicate detection itself only creates or uses this hash to determine if there are similar or exact matches. It does *not* evaluate the rules directly.

Based on the hash, which is created for the whole record, you are unable which rule(s) have led to this hash.